# JavaScript Function Access from jQuery UI tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI tabs in my web application, and I am loading each of the tab's content dynamically via Ajax. This way, I can keep each tab's content in separate HTML pages:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3.html">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4.html">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The JavaScript to instantiate the tabs is in my index.js, with the HTML being in index.html.

Now, I want to create an addTabs() function in index.js that can be called from any of the tab content pages (content1.html, content2.html, etc.).

How can I do this? I tried creating the function in index.js and simply calling it with `var id = addTab();`. This did not work, though, as I recevieved an error: "*Uncaught ReferenceError: addTab is not defined*". Here is the function:

```
function addTab(tabTitle) {
   // Add tab code          
   return id;
}
```

I also tried to use `$.getScript()` which will call the function, but I cannot access `var id` with what is returned outside of the `$.getScript()` function (I can only access it within the function).

I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

---

Here is the index.js file:

```
$(document).ready(

function () {

    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

    tabs.tabs('option', 'selected', 2);

    var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
    var tabCounter = 4;

    function addTab(tabTitle) {

        var label = tabTitle;
        var id = "tabs-" + tabCounter;
        var li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label));

        // 3 fixed tabs + 5 dynamic tabs
        if (tabCounter > 8) {
            $("#dialog").html(
                    'You have reached the maximum number of tabs allowed.').dialog(
                    "open");
            return -1;
        }

        $("#tabId").replaceWith(
                '<input type="hidden" name="tabId" id="tabId" value="' + id
                        + '" />');

        tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
        tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'></div>");

        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabCounter++;

        return id;
    }

});
```

Comment: It could be where you're placing the function inside `index.js`. It could be in a different scope than where you might be calling it. Without seeing the entire file, it's hard to say.

Comment: I have added the index.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the addTab function should be outside of document.ready so other files can access it

Comment: Initially commented on not having to do this, but after reading the question again, you are correct. The `addTab` function is scoped inside the function for the `document.ready` and can't be accessed once the ready is finished.